# Need hints about proving some intuitionistic logic statements

Tags: functional-programming, agda, dependent-type

I'm new to Agda, and I'm new to dependently typed programming and proof assistants in general. I decided to get myself started by constructing simple intuitionistic logic proofs, using the definitions I found in [Programming Language Foundations in Agda](https://plfa.github.io/), and I had some success. However, I got confused when I tried to write the following proof:

```
∨-identity-indirect : {A B : Set} → (¬ A) ∧ (A ∨ B) → B
```

Proving this on paper would be fairly simple: expanding `¬ A`, we have `A → ⊥`. So this statement becomes equivalent to `(⊥ ∨ B) → B`, which is obviously true.

I was able to successfully prove the latter part, that is, `(⊥ ∨ B) → B`:

```
∨-identity : {A : Set} → (⊥ ∨ A) → A
∨-identity (∨-left ())
∨-identity (∨-right A) = A
```

Then, I was able to write:

```
∨-identity-indirect ⟨ ¬A , A∨B ⟩ = ∨-identity ?
```

Suggesting me that I need to produce `⊥ ∨ B` by having `¬A` and `A ∨ B`. I'd like to somehow replace `A` in `A ∨ B` with `¬A A`, but I don't think there's a way of doing so.
When trying to apply the `∨-identity` case analysis pattern to `∨-identity-indirect`, I get an error message that *A should be empty, but that's not obvious to me* - I assume I need to somehow make this obvious to Agda, by making use of `¬A`.

Am I on the right track, or am I getting this wrong completely? How should I go about writing this `∨-identity-indirect` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suggesting me that I need to produce `⊥ ∨ B` by having `¬A` and `A ∨ B`. I'd like to somehow replace `A` in `A ∨ B` with `¬A A`, but I don't think there's a way of doing so.
>   When trying to apply the `∨-identity` case analysis pattern to `∨-identity-indirect`, I get an error message that *A should be empty, but that's not obvious to me* - I assume I need to somehow make this obvious to Agda, by making use of `¬A`.

You're probably trying to pattern match on a value of type `¬ A` with `()`, which doesn't work, because `¬ A` expands to `A -> ⊥`, i.e. it's a function that will only return you a `⊥` after you give it some `A`. Here is how you do that:

```
replace-A : {A B : Set} → (¬ A) → (A ∨ B) → ⊥ ∨ B
replace-A f (v-left  x) = v-left (f x)
replace-A _ (v-right y) = v-right y
```

Having that, `∨-identity-indirect` is straightforward:

```
∨-identity-indirect : {A B : Set} → (¬ A) ∧ (A ∨ B) → B
∨-identity-indirect ⟨ ¬A , A∨B ⟩ = ∨-identity (replace-A ¬A A∨B)
```